# Is there a way to display a large table in python with a scrollbar ?

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to display a large table (1000+ or lines, ~10 columns) in Python.

I have seen two approaches so far:

- pandas.tools.plotting.table: does the job, but does not have a scrollbar - it displays all in one window.
- Tinkter: has a scrollbar, but I could not find a nice interface for multiple columns (only list boxs), and ran into performance issues.

So my question is: is there a more straightfoward/efficient way to do that that I would have missed ?

Thank you.

Comment: If you're on linux, you can try to print it and use `less`: `./print_table.py | less`

Comment: I am adding a colour code etc...to the table.

Comment: unix has special color characters if you want to go that direction, less can display them. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/124407/what-color-codes-can-i-use-in-my-ps1-prompt